# Duplicity and Amazon S3 Script

Tags: backup, amazon-s3

I'm looking to backup my linux server to Amazon S3 using duplicity.

I found a great [resource here](http://www.randys.org/2007/11/16/how-to-automated-backups-to-amazon-s-s3-with-duplicity/) that helped me get it setup and am using the basic script that was listed there for me and now copied here:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Export some ENV variables so you don't have to type anything
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=[your-access-key-id]
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=[your-secret-access-key]
export PASSPHRASE=[your-gpg-passphrase]

GPG_KEY=[your-gpg-key]

# The source of your backup
SOURCE=/

# The destination
# Note that the bucket need not exist
# but does need to be unique amongst all
# Amazon S3 users. So, choose wisely.
DEST=s3+http://[your-bucket-name]/[backup-folder]

duplicity \
    --encrypt-key=${GPG_KEY} \
    --sign-key=${GPG_KEY} \
    --include=/boot \
    --include=/etc \
    --include=/home \
    --include=/root \
    --include=/var/lib/mysql \
    --exclude=/** \
    ${SOURCE} ${DEST}

# Reset the ENV variables. Don't need them sitting around
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
export PASSPHRASE=
```

Does anyone else have experience with duplicity where they can improve this script and/or share best practices to help create a better script?

Answer (score 15):

I am using a variation of that script for my backups. I recently made some changes to it, to try and save some money on my Amazon S3 bill (personal server, otherwise I wouldn't have minded so much).

The full script is [here](http://gist.github.com/15890), but I'll list the changes I made below.

```
--full-if-older-than 1M
--volsize 250
```

The first option makes sure that duplicity does a full backup regardless, every month. This is useful because it means I can remove to the latest full backup if I need to remove files from S3.

The second option decreases the number of files duplicity stores on S3, which decreases the number of requests made to S3, reducing the cost.

I also added the following after the backup has run. This removes any backups older than 6 months from S3.

```
duplicity remove-older-than 6M --force ${DEST}
```